# Installing LibreOffice on XUbuntu downloaded on another PC

Tags: xubuntu, libreoffice, versions

sorry for my english
Due to malfunctioning of my router, I downloaded Libreoffice for Linux(LibreOffice_4.1.0_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz) on a macintosh iBook G4, then copied the file ......-.tar.gz., by a memory stick, on a PC where I had just installed successfully XUbuntu-13.14 (same way: downloaded on mac and trasferred on PC for installing, was OK).

Double.click on the file for installing and I had this message (in Italian):
"Sequenza byte invalid nell'input di conversione"
I presume came from English "Invalid byte sequence in conversion input".
But what does it means?

I supposed corrupted data. I downloaded (in the same way, because in that moment I can not change my router) the file again. The result was the same.
Thinking due to a wrong version I downloaded other version:

LibreOffice_4.1.0_Linux_x86_deb.tar.gz
and
LibreOffice_4.1.0_Linux_x86-64_rpm.tar.gz

Always the same

Help me please

Biagio

Comment: You know that programs should be always installed from the Ubuntu Software Center? Click the Applications menu, then click on Ubuntu Software Center. LibreOffice will not be updated automatically if you install with the tar.gz. If you have Xubutnu 13.04, Ubuntu Software Center will install LibreOffice 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

The first time it failed was maybe due to corruption of data, but the second time, you downloaded the wrong file type. Download this [file from libreoffice.org](http://donate.libreoffice.org/home/dl/deb-x86/4.1.0/en-US/LibreOffice_4.1.0_Linux_x86_deb.tar.gz). After copying to your Xubuntu PC, extract the file. You will get a .deb file. Double click it to install

Answer (score 0):

You can install LibreOffice 4.1 with the PPA: https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa

Instructions for using the PPA: [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them)